# Does anybody know how to make an anchorScroll inside ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-include

I need to know how to make an anchorScroll to differents ID inside a ng-repeat menu.

```
<li data-ng-repeat="page in pages">
   <a href="{{href}}">{{ page.title }}</a>
</li>

<div id="1">One</div>
<div id="2">Two</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify - those divs are not within the li, so they are not considered part of the ng-repeat structure.

Comment: Yes. The divs are not part of the <li>. This is an example code because my code is too long to put here.

Comment: Is the question to scroll to those divs though, or something else?  If it is those divs, the premise of the question is incorrect - they are not actually part of the li ng-repeat.

Comment: You can see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/grevelles/MY6JL/

Comment: Your fiddle is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Within ng-repeat, you can use `index` to assign different IDs to each element.

```
<li data-ng-repeat="page in pages">
    <a id="link-{{page.index}}" href="{{href}}">{{ page.title }}</a>
</li>
```

The index will increment with each item in `pages`. The part in id where I put `link-` is optional; you can put whatever prefix or suffix you want that way.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this. I don't know what your objects look like, but this should be helpful.

HTML

```
<li data-ng-repeat="page in pages">
   <a href="" ng-click="scrollTo(page.index)">{{ page.title }}</a>
</li>

<div id="1">One</div>
<div id="2">Two</div>
```

Controller

```
$scope.pages = [
  { title: "test1", index: 1},
  { title: "test2", index: 2}
];
$scope.scrollTo = function(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).scrollIntoView();
};
```